# Bootstrap navbar-toggler-icon (3-bar stack) not showing when resizing the browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The three-bar "hamburger menu" is not showing when I resize the browser. The collapsed menu is there and works properly when I click on it, however it's just an invisible white box. I have closely compared my code to the Bootstrap source code and have not been able to identify any causes for this. The following is my navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top custom_nav_menu sticky">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand logo" id="main-name" href="#home">Name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
            aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#about" class="nav-link">What We Do</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#features" class="nav-link">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#client" class="nav-link">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#team" class="nav-link">Founding Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is a screenshot from the Developer Tools showing that it does exist, it's just not visible to the user.
[Screenshot of Developer Tools showing existence of the navbar toggler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm7IS.png)

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

navbar-toggler-icon isn't showing because of the id attribute in your code not having the same value as the data-toggler attribute on your button.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top custom_nav_menu sticky">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand logo" id="main-name" href="#home">Name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
            aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#about" class="nav-link">What We Do</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#features" class="nav-link">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#client" class="nav-link">Testimonials</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#team" class="nav-link">Founding Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I just changed the id to "collapse" in `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">` following data-toggle="collapse".

```
Hope that helps @Shadee Merhi
```

Comment: Hi Samiul, Thank you for the response. I tried changing it to id="collapse" and it didn't seem to fix it. It made it so when I clicked the invisible button, the menu did not pop down. I think that the data-target attribute is the one that has to match the id of the list.